# passing parameter to URL::to() method of laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I want a link in my html file to point to a `URL` using the `URL::to()` method. But I also want that, when someone clicks the link I can send some data with it. So, how can I pass parameter to `URL::to()` method of laravel. For ex.-

I want to do this-

```
URL::to('search')->with('x','12');
```

And I will place this method in my html file within '`{{}}`' as per Laravel docs. I have searched the net as well as laravel docs but couldn't find anything for this specific problem. And, I am not able to find any other way out to this.

**Update**: *Resolved. URL::route() did the work.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
link_to('foo/bar', $title, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);
```

For example:

```
{{ link_to('foo/bar/' . $param1, 'Goto Foo') }}
```

Or this way:

```
{{ link_to("foo/bar/$param1", 'Goto Foo') }}
```

[Check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls). Also, if you use `route` it would be easy to pass parameters in a separate array, `{{ route('routename', array('username' => $user->username))`.

Comment: route() and url::to() have the identical functioning?

Comment: @user1708762, No, they are different, `to()` accepts the `url` (`user/id/1`) and `route` accepts the `route name`, i.e. (`loginRoute`).

Comment: Hence, `to()` and `route()` both are helper functions and shortcut of `URL::to()` and `URL::route()`.